# Rules - After updating / saving user not working

Tags: rules

I'm using Rules module to execute a python script after a user has been created / updated. This python script retrieves information of users from the database and feeds a datapushing / realtime data engine.

Everything works perfect, BUT, the script is executing before saving.

**Update regarding 'script is executing before saving'**

When I get the information from the DB with the python script is the one I have before saving, the only workaround is saving twice. One to make changes, to second one to 'really' update. I've noticed this because I need to save twice to get real information.

I found this issue: http://drupal.org/node/430274

I thought on running the script in Drupal's User Core but good practices kind of don't let me do it ( for now :) )

**Update**

I created a Module with this Info

```
<?php
// $Id: infographic.module

/**
* @file
* Custom functions for this site.
*/
function infographic_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
    exec('python GenerateInfographic.py');
}

function infographic_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {
    exec('python GenerateInfographic.py');
}
```

Any Suggestion!?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the _script is executing before saving_. Drupal does drupal_write_record before the hook is executed so what exactly is your problem, are you using transactions in your database?

Comment: No, I access directly to the DB, I have updated concerning 'script is executing before saving'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`hook_user_insert`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) and [`hook_user_update`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) to execute your script, which is called after the user has been saved to the database.

Hooks should be implemented in a module. If you are new to module development, the Drupal documentation describes this very well: http://drupal.org/documentation

Comment: Thanks @googletorp, I'm kind of newbie on Drupal. Where can I found this hooks? Or should I implement a new class.

Comment: Ok, I've been investigating, http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7 here. Should I create a custom module with just an empty function ( hook_user_insert ) with the execute script? that's all?

Comment: @Xavi Updated with links

Comment: @Xavi Almost, create a custom module and create function called [name of module]_user_insert and do you things there.

Comment: Have the same problem I had with Rules. It's executed before saving. I updated my question with the code, which works, but before

Answer (score 0):

At least in D7, it worked for me calling

```
user_save($account);
```

at first. this it is if u need it changed in the own custom php rules code. I try to debug a message before/after that line of a load user and it seemed to work.

Actually, it didn't because i needed it changed because i was calling a script and in the script was getting the bad one, and i didn't have access to change that script.

So finally what it worked for me was calling the script in background:

```
$comando='php -f /var/www/moodle/auth/drupalservices/auth_drupalservices_sync_users.php '.$idUser.' >/var/tmp_files/output.txt &';
exec($comando);
```

and in the script putting a little sleep so i was sure was already changed in the other side :)

```
sleep(3);
```